ValueError:The field admin.LogEntry.user was declared with a lazy reference to 'recipes.customuser',but app'recipes'doesn't provide model 'customuser'
This is the Custom user model
I also declared in settings
AUTH_USER_MODEL="recipes.CustomUser"
still I face this error
ValueError:The field admin.LogEntry.user was declared with a lazy reference to 'recipes.customuser',but app'recipes'doesn't provide model 'customuser'`
from django.db import models
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser, Permission
from django.conf import settings
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
import secrets

class CustomUser(AbstractUser):
    email=models.EmailField(unique=True)
    
    USERNAME_FIELD="email"
    REQUIRED_FIELDS=["username"]
    
    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return self.email



Hi, welcome to SO. Your question seems unclear what you want to achieve, please add more details to the question. Share your setting file and other relevant info.

AUTH_USER_MODEL="recipes.CustomUser do you have your CustomUser set up in recipes app?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
